# How to configure lamda timeout via Skill project

Tags: aws-lambda, command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit

Is there easy way to configure aws-lambda timeout in Alexa Node.js Skill project configuration file?

I know how to set/reset aws-lambda timeout using console. However for auto deployment via CLI I would like to know how to set/reset this time via Alexa Node.Js Skill project

Comment: Every lambda related information is in the .ask/config file, such as the runtime information and the handler. 
You could try adding a "timeout" key with the number in seconds, as you can see in this link: https://github.com/aws/awsmobile-cli/issues/53
I'm not sure if its managed by the ask deploy command since the ask shell it's pretty recent and doesn't provide a every capability as the aws cli. If this fails, I'm afraid you will have to modify via aws cli or by web console.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this via skill config files, sorry